# Providing help in design-time for usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, design-time

I would like to provide Help when a developer press F1 in design-time when my user-control has focus. By default the Visual Studio help opens, but I would like to open my own online help.

I know you can use a custom designer for a user-control but it's a lot work for a simple task as opening an online help.

Does anyone has experience with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.design.ihelpservice%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

Answer (score -1):

Use the "HelpRequested" event of your control:

`button1.HelpRequested += button1_HelpRequested;`

and the implementation:

```
private void button1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)
{
   Help.ShowHelp(this, "helpFile.chm", HelpNavigator.TopicId, "1234");
}
```

Comment: Hi Nissim, does this work in design-time? I think this would only work in run-time.

Comment: @Devbg In design-time your code doesn't actually run. In order to override VS's 'F1' @ design time you will probably need to develop a VS extension. maybe the following could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942657/visual-studio-intercepting-f1-help-command